# How can I create a generic list monoid in scala that maintains the inner type of the list involved?

Tags: scala

I'm sure there must be some solution to this on the web, but I've been unable to find it. Suppose I have the following standard definition of a monoid in scala:

```
  trait Monoid[A] {
    def mappend(a1: A, a2: A): A
    def mzero: A
  }
```

Now, suppose I define an instance of a `Monoid` for a generic list:

```
  val listMonoid = new Monoid[List[_]] {
    def mappend(a1: List[_], a2: List[_]): List[_] = a1 ++ a2
    def mzero = Nil
  }
```

Now, suppose I try to use this monoid:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x: List[Int] = listMonoid.mappend(List(1), List(3))
    println(x)
  }
```

Unfortunately, `x` is a list of any type, so there is a compile error. What is the way to get around this?

Comment: Based on your series of questions, I think you might find the book Functional Programming in Scala interesting, which covers a lot of scalaz-esque stuff (written by two contributors to scalaz): http://manning.com/bjarnason/

Comment: Thanks, I was actually already waiting for that to come out on kindle :) (reading some Haskell books now). Would love to get input on the full example that I made if you or anyone had time to look: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51571/custom-scala-implementation-of-generic-future-sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` as a type parameter means "I don't care what this type is, so please forget it immediately", which isn't what you want. Instead of using a `val`, you can use a `def` with a type parameter that will allow you to keep track of the item type:

```
def listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
  def mappend(a1: List[A], a2: List[A]): List[A] = a1 ++ a2
  def mzero = Nil
}
```

Your `main` method will still work, since the appropriate type parameter will be inferred. If you want to use this to generate type class instances in the usual way, just add an `implicit` in front of the `def`.